# Visual Studio REST API Changesets Limit

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using the Visual Studio Online REST API to fetch changeset data from my server.  A problem that I'm encountering is that there seems to be a limit to changeset data returned.  This limit seems to be capping at 255.

To retrieve my changesets, I use the following url:

> ```
> https://< account >.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_apis/tfvc/changesets?$top=255&api-version=1.0-preview
> ```

This will yield an expected 255 results (due to setting the `$top=255` parameter); however, if I supply anything over 255, `...$top=256` for example, the server seems to break down and return an arbitrary number - in my case, 91 total records.

I know that I have over 1,000 changeset records, though it seems I can only reliably return a maximum of 255 records.

Has anyone encountered this, and if so, how did you work around this cap?

I have tried using a date range and it still yields the same results. Example:

> https://< account >.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_apis/tfvc/changesets?$top=256&searchCriteria.fromDate=2000-01-01&searchCriteria.toDate=2015-01-01&api-version=1.0-preview

The above only returns 91 records, and yet I would expect to see 256.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [API documentation](http://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/reference/reference-vso-version-control-changesets-vsi), you will need to include `$skip` to *page* through the results.

The first 255

```
https://{account}.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_apis/tfvc/changesets?$top=255&api-version={version}
```

The next 255

```
https://{account}.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_apis/tfvc/changesets?$skip=255&$top=255&api-version={version}
```

... and so on.